# read httppost request messages without a server

Tags: java, servlets

I have a third party server that is periodically sending http post request messages to an URL(can be configured). In my application I am reading data by starting a jetty server and listening for data on the configured URL. 
Wondering if it is possible to listen for the data sent by the server without starting any server like the jetty?

Comment: Can you have an HTTP server without jetty? Yes, there are many choices. Can you have an HTTP server without an HTTP server? No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always create a socket yourself and listen at port 80 (or something similar) for HTTP requests. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html

But there are several problems: Theres a lot of overhead that you need to do yourself. Parse the HTTP request, extract the headers and the body and depending on the headers you need to do certain things like caching, authentication, etc. And that's a lot of stuff you need to implement. Using an existing web server is usually a better idea, since the people who wrote it (usually) know exactly what they are doing.

Another option is the Apache HttpCore library (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/index.html). You can use it to write your own Http Server... But again, there's still a lot of stuff you need to take care of ...

If you want to do it for learning purposes, go ahead and implement it yourself. When it is for production, stick with the commonly used web servers.

Comment: is it not an overhead to start the jetty server? If I have like thousands of http request messages coming in, would the jetty server create several servlet threads and take up most of the jvm execution time

Comment: But jetty knows how to handle those, because the jetty developers thought about scaling ... You can try different servers like tomcat/catalina, etc and see which one scales best in your situation. In some edge cases it might be good to write your own server, but I think in that situation you are describing you are doing better with something off the shelf

Comment: Can't agree more with the last point. In all honesty, vjk, if you're already asking how to listen for HTTP requests without a HTTP server, you'd better not to start reinventing a HTTP server yourself (yet).

Comment: and what about sending data to the server. currently I am using the apache httpclient for sending post request. would it be a better option to use httpclient from the jetty. I need to handle both the synchronous and asynchronous communication

Comment: I don't think there's a huge difference. But nobody can give you a definite answer on that. You can Create a version with either one and then do some performance testing. That's the only way to find out... But unless you are somewhere around a few hundred requests per second, you shouldn't worry about it